# C++ struct template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I am trying to develop my own 3d renderer, and I need a 3D vector struct for this. I am trying to make this the most generic as possible, so I'm using templated structures.

I created a `Vec<size_t, typename>` structure and for simplicity, I specialized Vec<2, typename> to have the x and y properties. Like this:

```cpp
template <size_t DIM, typename T>
struct Vec
{
    T data[DIM];

    Vec() : data() {}

    Vec(std::vector<T> _data)
    {
        assert(_data.size() == DIM);
        for (int i = DIM; i--; data[i] = _data[i])
            ;
    }

    template <typename U>
    Vec(Vec<DIM, U> v)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++)
            data[i] = (T)v[i];
    }

    T &operator[](size_t idx)
    {
        return data[idx];
    }
};

template <size_t LEN, size_t DIM, typename T>
Vec<LEN, T> embed(Vec<DIM, T> &v, T fill = 1)
{
    Vec<LEN, T> ret;
    for (size_t i = LEN; i--; ret[i] = (i < DIM ? v[i] : fill))
        ;
    return ret;
}

template <size_t LEN, size_t DIM, typename T>
Vec<LEN, T> proj(Vec<DIM, T> &v)
{
    Vec<LEN, T> ret;
    for (size_t i = LEN; i--; ret[i] = v[i])
        ;
    return ret;
}


template <typename T>
struct Vec<2, T>
{
    union
    {
        T data[2];
        struct
        {
            T x, y;
        };
    };
};

typedef Vec<2, int> Vec2i;
typedef Vec<2, float> Vec2f;
typedef Vec<2, double> Vec2d;
```

But when I do this, I get this error:

```cpp
...
/src/main.cpp:61:62: error: no matching function for call to ‘Vec<2, int>::Vec(Vec<2, double>)’
   61 |                 verts[i] = (Vec<2, int>)proj<2>(face.verts[i]);
      |                                                              ^
...
/include/geometry.h:52:8: note: candidate: ‘Vec<2, int>::Vec()’
   52 | struct Vec<2, T>
      |        ^~~~~~~~~
/include/geometry.h:52:8: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/include/geometry.h:52:8: note: candidate: ‘constexpr Vec<2, int>::Vec(const Vec<2, int>&)’
/include/geometry.h:52:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Vec<2, double>’ to ‘const Vec<2, int>&’
/include/geometry.h:52:8: note: candidate: ‘constexpr Vec<2, int>::Vec(Vec<2, int>&&)’
/include/geometry.h:52:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Vec<2, double>’ to ‘Vec<2, int>&&’
/include/geometry.h: In instantiation of ‘Vec<LEN, T> proj(Vec<DIM, T>&) [with long unsigned int LEN = 2; long unsigned int DIM = 3; T = double]’:
/src/main.cpp:61:62:   required from here
/include/geometry.h:46:34: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘Vec<2, double>’ and ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’})
   46 |     for (size_t i = LEN; i--; ret[i] = v[i])
      |                               ~~~^
...
```

The Vec<2, T> didn't inherit the functions? Why I'm getting these errors?

Comment: A specialization replaces everything in the primary template, not just the pieces you wish it to replace. If you want the specialization to have those member functions, you need to define them there.

Answer (score 2):

A class specialization is a blank slate; you have to provide the entire implementation which can be a lot of duplication. That does not seem like a good fit for the use case you present: adding convenience accessors depending on the dimension.

I would suggest having a single template class with accessors that are conditionally enabled based on the dimension. This adds some clutter to reading the class, but there is no code duplication.

Also, since the dimension is a template parameter, you can use `std::array` for the data member.

The following code demonstrates these ideas. It uses some advanced language features, so you may have to adapt the implementation details depending on what version of the language you are using.

### Sample Code

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cin, std::cout, std::endl;


template<size_t D, class T>
struct Vec {
    Vec() : data_() { }

    template<class... Us> requires (sizeof...(Us) == D and (std::is_convertible_v<Us, T> and ...))
    Vec(Us... args)
        : data_({args...}) {
    }

    Vec(const std::vector<T>& other) {
        assert(other.size() == D);
        std::copy(other.begin(), other.end(), data_.begin());
    }

    template<class U>
    Vec(const Vec<D, U>& other) {
        std::copy(other.begin(), other.end(), data_.begin());
    }

    auto& operator[](size_t idx) { return data_[idx];  }
    const auto& operator[](size_t idx) const { return data_[idx]; }

    T& x() { return data_[0]; }
    const T& x() const { return data_[0]; }

    T& y() requires (D > 1) { return data_[1]; }
    const T& y() const requires (D > 1) { return data_[1];  }

    T& z() requires (D > 2) { return data_[2]; }
    const T& z() const requires (D > 2) { return data_[2]; }

    T& w() requires (D > 3) { return data_[3]; }
    const T& w() const requires (D > 3) { return data_[3]; }

private:
    std::array<T, D> data_;
};


int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    Vec<1, int> a(1);
    cout << a.x() << endl;

    Vec<2, int> b(1, 2);
    cout << b.x() << " " << b.y() << endl;

    Vec<3, int> c(1, 2, 3);
    cout << c.x() << " " << c.y() << " " << c.z() << endl;

    Vec<4, int> d(1, 2, 3, 4);
    cout << d.x() << " " << d.y() << " " << d.z() << " " << d.w() << endl;
}
```

### Output

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. This is a nice solution. Do you think that is possible to use this conditional declaration to declare x, y, and z as variables and not a function? I don't like this function call hahaha... but anyway, this helps me a lot! Thanks

Comment: this code is throwing errors on the compilation... Are you sure this is right?

Comment: It compiled clearing using `clang-16` on `MacOSX`, but on `Ubuntu` the compiler complained about `std::vector`. I updated the code to include `vector` which fixed the issue. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/Y7osPb8vE) is the `Godbolt` link. I am using `c++20` and I haven't tried `c++17` or earlier.